# How would a male brain in a female body effect hormone production and what other effects would it have on the body?

Tags: body-modification

I think it was in a tales from the crypt episode, where a bio scientist experimenting with head transfer, discovered that his wife had an affair, so as revenge he swapped their two heads.
This is similar in a way to the comic The Metabarons, where the current metabaron´s grandfather Steelhead was left with a choice.

His wife where dying and was expecting twins a boy and a girl, however because of her situation only one of the children could be saved.

Out of love Steelhead chose to save the girl, but discovered the her cranium was empty so he transplanted the brain from the boy to the girl´s head.

Now my question is how much say does the brain have in which hormones are being produced in our body, and what effects would (based on what we know about the brain and the production of hormones) swapping either the brain or the head from a man to a woman or vice versa have on the body of the one receiving the transplant if this was done in real life?

Comment: By the time this happened, the rest of the body would have been adjusted by hormones and the rest of the hormonal system would drive changes in the transplanted brain.

Comment: @Gridlock  Male brain?  Female brain?  This makes me picture someone saying "when a daddy brain loves a mommy brain they make a baby brain and put it in a new body".

Answer (score 13):

**The male brain would run the female body just fine**

The pituitary is in the brain and the hormones it makes are the qualitatively the same in men and women.  The difference is quantity and timing.  For example the pituitary makes gonadotropin releasing hormone.  That works on testes or ovaries, whichever you have.  The brain detects the sex hormone products of these glands in the body and moderates its activity depending on what it detects.  FSH waxes and wanes in a woman depending on hormone levels produced by the ovaries - in men it stays constant because of relatively (as compared to a menstrual cycle) constant testosterone level.  The brain (pituitary again) will make prolactin and promote breast growth / lactation if (simplified) estrogen levels are high; in a man prolactin never normally gets that high.

Hormones from the brain and hormones from the body are in a dialogue.  If the body starts sending up hormones from the opposite gender, because you are a transgender person getting hormone therapy or because your brain is in a new body, the brain is adaptable.

Answer (score 2):

The brain would change as it's competing with other hormonal messengers.  People who decide t hey want to change sex via hormone replacement experience psychological changes.
Women become less emotional.

Comment: Good point, I'm surprised Willk missed that. Welcome to Worldbuilding, enjoy the site. (From review)

Answer (score -4):

The human brain is genderless, the same way your hand or liver are genderless.
The brain is shaped by the hormones it receives.

Guys abusing certain performance enhancing drugs often change their sexuality/gender identity as a side effect.
other side effects are engorged nipples and lactation as well as balding and shriking of testicles.

The  Y chromoses has so few genes inside, it makes almost no difference in the human body... gender differences are almost entirely hormonal.

You could look at trasexual people for example, the idea of a male brain stuck in a female body or vice verse. A good chunk of people going through hormonal replacement ''change their mind'' after a few months or years... some going back to being their previous gender or some even becoming something even more ''distant'' than what they were born as.

A good anecdotal example is Contrapoints on youtube, she went from male to female and through the years of hormonal replacement she changed her sexuality 5 or 6 times.  It's not that people  are actually dumb enough to not even know their own sexuality or gender, no one is that much confused. Your brain reacts to hormones, it's a  not confusion or a decision, it's just different hormonal balances.

During history some men had their balls cut off to be sold by their parents as prostitutes or singers, study them if you are curious about the effects of a ''male brain'' inside a female body.

Also look what happens to females taking performace enchancing drugs for the opposite effect.

Comment: The human brain *begins* its development as genderless, or, actually, female. (All mammalian embryos start their development on the female plan.) But, if the embryo is to develop into a boy, the brain is rearranged in the later part of the pregnancy. No, we don't know what this rearrangement does. (Because in general we know very little about how the brain works.) Then the male brain is rearranged again at puberty. The effect is that post-puberty a male brain went through two rearrangement processes. It might be that those processes have little importance; or they might have great importance.